# Count instances of consecutive dates for associated name (VBA, SQL)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Good morning all,

I am trying to determine instances of consecutive dates (excluding Sunday) from a data set. The data is stored in Access and I am pulling the required dates into Excel. I am then trying to determine how many instances each person has in the data provided. Example below.

Data example:

```
| Name | Date of absence|
| Bob  | 02/01/17       | 
| Jill | 02/01/17       |
| Bob  | 03/01/17       |
| Jill | 04/01/17       |
```

Result example:

```
Bob - 1 Instance, 2 days
Jill - 2 Instance, 2 days
```

I started trying to work through this with VBA in Excel using loops to rotate through each instance of absence until all people had been completed/ticked off, however the code was becoming really cumbersome and it felt very inefficient, not to mention how slow it was getting for larger data sets! I wonder if it is possible to query the database for the info or to write something a bit more efficient.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Update:

Testing Tom's suggestion;
`Sql = "SELECT Absence.Racf,count(RecordDate) as dups"
Sql = Sql & " FROM Absence"
Sql = Sql & " left outer join"
Sql = Sql & " (select Racf, [RecordDate]+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as date1 from Absence) t1"
Sql = Sql & " on Absence.RecordDate=t1.date1 and Absence.Racf=t1.Racf"
Sql = Sql & " where date1 Is Not Null"
Sql = Sql & " group by Absence.Racf"`

But unfortunately on the list of dates below it returns 7, instead of 5.

Dates:
23-Feb-16,24-Feb-16,08-Aug-16,09-Aug-16,10-Aug-16,31-Aug-16,24-Oct-16,25-Oct-16,26-Oct-16,25-Jan-17,26-Jan-17,27-Jan-17

Comment: First of all, change the query of data extraction and add `order by Name,Date_of_absence`.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could do it more easily in Access? Basically you need a self join with a condition that the dates differ by 1 (with an extra condition for Sundays), but because Access is fussy you might need to do it with a query that advances the date by one and then join that to the original table.

Comment: Yes I did wonder about that. My query picks out all pairs of consecutive dates for the same person so a group of three would count twice. I think it can be fixed but putting in another self join going back a day but it was a little unclear from the original question.

Comment: Plz see updated answer - not fully tested for Sundays but seems to be on right lines

Comment: Also added query to include just a single date as a sequence - now your original example makes more sense with Jill having two instances!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how the SQL might actually look in an Access query

```
SELECT table1.name,count(date) as dups
FROM Table1
left outer join
(select name, [date]+IIf(Weekday([Date],7)=1,2,1) as date1 from table1) t1
on table1.date=t1.date1 and table1.name=t1.name    
where date1 is not null
group by table1.name
;
```

If you want to run this from Excel using a macro, [here](http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/10/running-access-queries-from-excel-vba.html) is a useful reference.

I lifted the code from there and changed the lines which set up the SQL query string to

```
SQL = "SELECT table1.name,count(date) as dups"
SQL = SQL & " FROM table1"
SQL = SQL & " left outer join"
SQL = SQL & " (select name, [date]+IIf(Weekday([Date],7)=1,2,1) as date1 from table1) t1"
SQL = SQL & " on table1.date=t1.date1 and table1.name=t1.name"
SQL = SQL & " where date1 Is Not Null"
SQL = SQL & " group by table1.name"
```

and it worked fine.

Try this if you want to get sequences with length greater than one

```
SELECT Absence.Racf, Count(Absence.RecordDate) AS CountOfRecordDate
FROM (Absence LEFT JOIN (select Racf, RecordDate+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as RecordDate1 from Absence) AS t1 ON (Absence.RecordDate = t1.RecordDate1) AND (Absence.Racf = t1.Racf))
LEFT JOIN (select Racf, [RecordDate]-IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],2)=1,2,1) as RecordDate2 from Absence) AS t2 ON (Absence.RecordDate = t2.RecordDate2) AND (Absence.Racf = t2.Racf)
WHERE (((t1.RecordDate1) Is Not Null) AND ((t2.RecordDate2) Is Null))
GROUP BY Absence.Racf;
```

Or this if you want to get sequences of one or more consecutive dates

```
SELECT Absence.Racf, Count(Absence.RecordDate) AS CountOfRecordDate
FROM Absence LEFT JOIN (select Racf, [RecordDate]+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as RecordDate2 from Absence) AS t2 ON (Absence.RecordDate = t2.RecordDate2) AND (Absence.Racf = t2.Racf)
WHERE (((t2.RecordDate2) Is Null))
GROUP BY Absence.Racf;
```

adding to the SQL string as before.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Tom. I will give it a go.

Comment: Hope it works for you. Looking at it again, I don't know why I didn't use an inner join, but results should be the same as outer join plus 'where' clause.

Comment: I tried amending this to be used from Excel but without much luck. Is there something key that needs to change that I might be missing? I renamed all of the tables and fields to match my db.

Comment: Are you submitting the query from Excel with a macro? I must admit I have never needed to do this so might not be able to help much although I can give it a try later if I get time.

Comment: That's right, I keep everything in Excel (for better or worse) and only use Access as the storage facility.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for the continued support. If I am reading that right the code is the same, only that it is being passed as a string, is that correct or have I missed something? When passing it to the SQL query from Excel I had converted it to a string in a similar format to above.

Comment: Yes that's right, I just wanted to satisfy myself that it would work if I passed it through from Excel.

Comment: Oh, did it work from you? I converted it in the same way but it returned an error (too few parameters).

Comment: Yes, it was fine. Is it worth trying just a one line select * to make sure all the code around it is working properly? I'm not sure what to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Sql = "SELECT Absence.Racf,count(RecordDate) as dups"
Sql = Sql & " FROM Absence"
Sql = Sql & " left outer join"
Sql = Sql & " (select Racf, [RecordDate]+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as date1 from Absence) t1"

Too few parameters, expected 1. I tried with select * and removing the group statement to compensate but I had the same error. When I have changed out the table/field names I assume I made a mistake, can you spot it?
Sql = Sql & " on Absence.RecordDate=t1.date1 and Absence.Racf=t1.name"
Sql = Sql & " where date1 Is Not Null"
Sql = Sql & " group by Absence.Racf"

Comment: I must admit I don't really understand what the error message is trying to say, but I can spot one error where t1.name in the ON clause should have been changed to t1.Racf

Comment: Oh darnit. Thanks Tom, such a silly mistake by me. That returns without error now! Unfortunately it isn't quite right. This comment thread is getting huge so I will post in my question...

Comment: This time it returned 4 instead of 7. (expected 5) Getting closer! I really appreciate your tenacity with this, Tom. Thank you, profusely. I wouldn't have got anywhere with this without your help.

Comment: You've lost me now, I can only count 4 separate sequences so I think it's giving the right answer. Or do you mean that 31-Aug-16, although an isolated day, is a sequence in its own right? Stretching the concept of 'consecutive' a bit. It's actually an easier question if that is true because you just have to look for the start of each sequence.

Comment: Tom, that's it! You're amazing, thank you ever so much! I am not expecting you to do this last bit, you have done so much already, but would it be simple enough to get it to look between two dates? Would I wrap the main query in the date query?

Comment: Great, we got there in the end. I think you would have to add any further conditions to both the inner and outer queries, or it might be easier to add min or max of RecordDate and then filter the results in Excel? No, that wouldn't work because you only get one max or min date per name.

Comment: I'll try adding it to the inner and outer. Thanks Tom, I really appreciate all of your support.

Comment: On second thoughts just doing the outer query should be OK but anyway hopefully you can test it from there.

Comment: I am not making much progress with this, Tom, so I will post a new question. Just wanted to thank you once more.

Comment: Hi @Tom , I am sorry to ask more of you but I have been unable to solve the addition of a date range and my new question on that issue has gone unanswered. Do you have any suggestions you might be able to share? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Snayff Well I might have misled you because you have to apply the date range condition _after_ the selection and grouping i.e. it has to be in a HAVING clause. I will put it in your new question. Sorry for any hassle that might have caused.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only test this at work because I don't have Access at home and I am now going to be off for a few days but I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using array formula in Excel.  In D I have `=INDEX($A2:$A$15,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:$D1,$A2:$A$15),0))` to get the unique employees, then in E I have the following to count the instances `=SUM(--(($A$1:$A$15=D1)*(OFFSET($A$1:$A$15,1,0)=D1)*(OFFSET($B$1:$B$15,1,0)-$B$1:$B$15)=1))` which gives the result something like this.  You'll need to add another criteria, based on `weekday`  (I will adjust a little later as running low on time)   This relies on the data being in date order

[image]

EDIT : I understand this is not the full answer and will require modification, a starting point :o)

Covering the Sunday absence (will still need weekday check):

`=D1 & " " & COUNTIF($A$1:$A$15,D1) &" instances " & SUM(--(--($A$1:$A$15=D1)*--(OFFSET($A$1:$A$15,1,0)=D1))*--(--(OFFSET($B$1:$B$15,1,0)-$B$1:$B$15=1)+--(OFFSET($B$1:$B$15,1,0)-$B$1:$B$15=2)))&" Consecutive"`

Checking the weekday also

`=D2 & " " & COUNTIF($A$1:$A$15,D2) &" instances " & SUM(--(--($A$1:$A$15=D2)*--(OFFSET($A$1:$A$15,1,0)=D2))*--(--(OFFSET($B$1:$B$15,1,0)-$B$1:$B$15=1)+--(WEEKDAY(OFFSET($B$1:$B$15,1,0),2)=1)*((OFFSET($B$1:$B$15,1,0)-$B$1:$B$15=2)))) & " Consecutive"`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response Nathan. If it can be done through a worksheet formula that would fit what I need even better. I already have a list of unique names so adding your second formula to utilise that...  `=SUM(--((Data!H3:H60=B11)*(OFFSET(Data!H3:H60,1,0)=B11)*(OFFSET(Data!K3:K60,1,0)-Data!K3:K60)=1))`
with B11 being the name to look for, Data!H being the list of names and Data!K being the dates. 

Unfortunately it returns 0, even when input as an array. I will have a play with what you wrote and see if I can wrangle it in to playing nice.

Comment: It relies on consecutive entries, so in your o.p it will count bob as having 2 consecutive days off, jill will be 0 `OFF‌​SET(Data!K3:K60,1,0)‌​-Data!K3:K60)=1)`

Comment: youll need something like `(OFF‌​SET(Data!K3:K60,1,0)‌​-Data!K3:K60)=1)+OFF‌​SET(Data!K3:K60,1,0)‌​-Data!K3:K60)=2))`

Comment: Sorry Nathan, what's the latter one doing? And I need to count total instances, where consecutive days count as one instance. So in my original example Jill has 2 instances, not 0. Is this still possible?

Comment: Yes, see the edit, checking if the next day absence is 1 day or 2.

Comment: edit: I am a fool and forgot the array, ignore me. Fantastic work, Nathan, thank you.

Comment: I am sure it is a simple tweak but I am not certain how the formula works so I wanted to ask. It currently counts any periods of more than 1 day (consecutive) and all occurrences of the name (instance). What needs to change to make it show the total periods of absence. Single days and multiple days would count for one each, so you might have 5 days of absence in 3 periods and I am looking for the 3. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

A SQL approach would be something along the lines of, based on a table 000Absence, which is the data from examples EEName and AbsDate.

```
SELECT abs1.EEName, abs1.AbsDate, 
(select count(abs2.EEName) from 000Absence as abs2 where abs2.[EEName]=abs1.[EEName]) AS INSTANCES, 
(select count(abs3.EEName) from 000Absence as abs3 where abs3.[EEName]=abs1.[EEName] and abs3.[AbsDate]=abs1.[AbsDate]+iif(weekday(abs3.[AbsDate],7)=1,2,1)) AS CONSECUTIVE
FROM 000Absence AS abs1;
```

Where the output can be got from the query, grouping by Employee etc.

Comment: I tried this out and it returned information similar to the worksheet formula you suggested. 
|  Name |  RecordDate |  INSTANCES | CONSECUTIVE |
| Bob | 04/01/2016 |  | 103 | 1 |  
Unfortunately I only need the amount of periods the person has been absent, even if that period is a single day. Is it possible to do that and to also check between date points?
I appreciate your help with this, Nathan.