# Finding Consecutive and single instance dates, between two dates, in Access(SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Morning all,

I want to know every instance of absence, where an instance is any single day or set of consecutive days, between two date points. I had extensive help on this in my original question and have working code for everything except the "Between two dates" part. I am hoping someone can help me to add the "between two dates" element to the working code.

Example question:
How many instances, and total days, of absence has everyone had between 03/01/16 and 19/01/16?

Sample data:

```
|IDRef  |RecordDate  |Racf  |Type  |LengthOfAbsence 
|1788  |04-Jan-16  |Bob  |Sickness |420
|1789  |04-Jan-16  |Jill  |Sickness |420 
|1790  |05-Jan-16  |Bob  |Sickness |420 
|1791  |17-Jan-16  |Jill|Sickness |420  
|1792  |18-Jan-16  |Bob  |Sickness |420
```

Expected output:

```
| Racf  |Total Days  |Instances
|Bob  | 3  |2  
|Jill  |2  |2
```

Working code:

```
SELECT Absence.Racf, Count(Absence.RecordDate) AS CountOfRecordDate
FROM Absence LEFT JOIN (select Racf, [RecordDate]+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as RecordDate2 from Absence) AS t2 ON (Absence.RecordDate = t2.RecordDate2) AND (Absence.Racf = t2.Racf)
WHERE (((t2.RecordDate2) Is Null))
GROUP BY Absence.Racf;
```

My most recent attempt to amend it to only look between two dates (this doesn't cause an error but does return unexpected/incorrect values):

```
Sql = "SELECT Absence.Racf, Count(Absence.RecordDate) AS CountOfRecordDate "
Sql = Sql & "FROM Absence LEFT JOIN (select Racf, [RecordDate]+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as RecordDate2 from Absence where [RecordDate] BETWEEN #" & sFromDate & "# AND #" & sToDate & "#) AS t2 ON (Absence.RecordDate = t2.RecordDate2) AND (Absence.Racf = t2.Racf) "
Sql = Sql & "WHERE (((t2.RecordDate2) Is Null)) AND [t2.RecordDate2] BETWEEN #" & sFromDate & "# AND #" & sToDate & "# "
Sql = Sql & "GROUP BY Absence.Racf;"
```

Original question here: [Count instances of consecutive dates for associated name (VBA, SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040832/count-instances-of-consecutive-dates-for-associated-name-vba-sql)

Any help with this last step would be greatly appreciated, an explanation of why it works wouldn't hurt, either, as I have no idea!

Comment: your last `Sql` lack closing quotation - should be `Sql = Sql & "GROUP BY Absence.Racf;"` or this is just a typo

Comment: What's wrong with the new code? What does it do that's wrong? throw an error, give the wrong result? ie - what is your actual question here?

Comment: @Charlesliam Thank you for point that out, it was a typo and I have amended the question.

Comment: @BeanFrog I have updated the question, thank you for helping me to be more clear. There is not an error, however it does not return the expected values.

Comment: What values does it give and what values do you want? Sample data please! See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Comment: And also see here: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks BeanFrog. Hopefully that is better presented and explained now.

Comment: @BeanFrog Does the update question help at all? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my new working code that I have tested in Access but not yet in a macro called from Excel

```
SELECT Absence.Racf, Count(Absence.RecordDate) AS CountOfRecordDate, Absence.RecordDate
FROM Absence LEFT JOIN [select Racf, [RecordDate]+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as RecordDate2 from Absence]. AS t2 ON (Absence.Racf = t2.Racf) AND (Absence.RecordDate = t2.RecordDate2)
WHERE (((t2.RecordDate2) Is Null))
GROUP BY Absence.Racf, Absence.RecordDate
HAVING (((Absence.RecordDate)>#1/1/2016# And (Absence.RecordDate)<#10/11/2016#));
```

The reason a date range didn't work in the WHERE clause was that the date here is always NULL so you never get any records.

You could equally well use a BETWEEN statement instead of > and <.

I'm sorry this isn't the neat solution you were looking for, but this is getting beyond what you can easily do in a single query in Access. The output looks like this

[image]

What I suggest you do (if you imagine this for several users) is to use a pivot table to summarise the results for each user.

But you may also try this

```
SQL = "select racf, count(racf) AS Instances from ("
SQL = SQL & "SELECT Absence.Racf, Count(Absence.RecordDate) AS CountOfRecordDate,Absence.RecordDate"
SQL = SQL & " FROM (Absence LEFT JOIN (select Racf, RecordDate+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as RecordDate1 from Absence) AS t1 ON (Absence.RecordDate = t1.RecordDate1) AND (Absence.Racf = t1.Racf))"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE ((t1.RecordDate1) Is Null) "
SQL = SQL & " GROUP BY Absence.Racf,Absence.RecordDate"
SQL = SQL & " HAVING (((Absence.RecordDate)>#1/1/2016# And (Absence.RecordDate)<#10/11/2016#))"
SQL = SQL & ") AS T0 GROUP BY RACF"
```

EDIT

I'm sure on reflection that although correct, this can be simplified because the inner GROUP BY isn't serving any useful purpose - the HAVING clause should be brought outside T0 as a WHERE clause.

It should look like this

```
SQL = "select racf, count(racf) AS Instances from ("
SQL = SQL & "SELECT Absence.Racf, Absence.RecordDate"
SQL = SQL & " FROM (Absence LEFT JOIN (select Racf, RecordDate+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as RecordDate1 from Absence) AS t1 ON (Absence.RecordDate = t1.RecordDate1) AND (Absence.Racf = t1.Racf))"
SQL = SQL & " WHERE ((t1.RecordDate1) Is Null) "
SQL = SQL & ") AS T0 WHERE (((RecordDate)>#1/1/2016# And (RecordDate)<#10/11/2016#))"
SQL = SQL & "GROUP BY RACF"
```

EDIT

Have now tested this and it does work but a date like #10/11/2016# is ambiguous - although my locale is UK it appeared to be interpreted as October 11th 2016.

Suggest using instead

```
Datevalue(""10 November 2016"")
```

where quotes have to be doubled up because they appear in a quoted string.

Comment: Thank you for this, Tom.  I tried the first code directly in Access and I got a syntax error on the FROM clause, on RecordDate+IIf . When I run it from Excel, as well as the latter untested code, it returns some people but not the amount expected. I used the BETWEEN, too, but it delivered the same. The latter code does run in Access, but it again returns less than expected. When I just run a return on the RACFs with RecordDates between two points I return 10 unique RACFs, using the latter code above it only returns 5 RACFs. Does that make sense?

Comment: Would it be another option to run a query to return the records between two points and then a second query to find the instances on those returned records? I have no issue with it being over multiple queries, so long as I can run it from Excel.

Comment: You could do it with two queries if you were working directly in Access, but I can't see how you would do it from Excel because the first query would have to exist before you could run the second query. I don't see why you're getting a smaller number of records with a date select if the dates are spanning all the records in the original table. Have you followed up the other approach, that is getting the start date of each sequence using the first query (I think you only need the first 3 lines without the count) then using pivot table & filter in Excel?

Comment: Thank  you for your continued support Tom (I hope you had a nice Easter). I tried the second approach but I couldn't get the SELECT query to run - errors in the FROM relating to RACF. Thinking of another way to do it; I can run queries from Excel so what about calling some queries to put the required info in to another table, then I can run a SELECT query on that quite easily? I expect it would work something like: <clear the table> // <find all absences between dates and append to table> // <reduce to instances> - Does that make sense and would it be easier?

Comment: Easter was good thanks, hope the same with you. Sounds like a good idea, I've often used a make-table query in Access when things got too complicated to do something just with a series of queries. So if sending it from Excel you would need "select [columns] into [new table] from [existing table] where [date range]". Once again, I can't test it until I'm back at work next week so can't be very specific (also I'm not sure if it would stop you over-writing an existing table so caution would be advised).

Comment: It does stop the MAKETABLE, so I suspect it would need to be an append, after a clearing of the table. I can happily pull across the dates between determined points, however it is the turning it in to instances that leaves me floundering. Would it be similar to your first answer, in my original question?

Comment: That did it! Thank you ever so much, Tom. I will add an answer so that the steps are clearly clarified for anyone else but I couldn't have done it without you, not by a long shot! Thank you, Tom, all the best.

Comment: Thanks @Snayff, glad it worked in the end. Have edited the answer but seemed OK apart from interpreting dates as MM/DD/YYYY instead of DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: It might have just been that then, I marked it as the answer. Not to be accused of moving goal posts... It occurs to me that if someone is absent Mon-Fri then the following Mon that it should count as one instance, as they have worked their 5 day pattern. Each person can work 5 days between Mon-Sat and if the absence for that week is 5 then it can move to the next week when considering if part of the same instance. That seems quite a bit more complicated that what was already a challenging query. Tom, do you have any suggestions on tackling it?

Comment: I'm finding it a bit difficult to get my head round if I'm honest. So assuming they are on a flexible working pattern Monday-Saturday, would that mean that if they put _any_ five days down as absent in a working week they should join on to the next week's absence (which might not even start on Monday)? I'm OK with SQL but not one of the really clever ones, suggest putting some examples into a new question and seeing if it gets picked up (but I do like a challenge and will certainly think about it!)

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, Tom (and apologies for the delay, I have been out of the business). Given how complicated this is getting I am going to try and see if I can leverage a change in the data to make my life easier. Thanks again, Tom!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tom's answers I finally got there.

To retrieve instances of individual or consecutive dates, within a date range, here is what worked:

- Created a new table to hold the dates required.
- Run a query held in Access, from Excel to append the required records, between the date points, in to the new table.
- Run a Select query from Excel to return the instances, excluding Sundays.

To run the query from Excel (db already defined as OpenDatabase):

```
db.QueryDef.Execute
```

Append query:

```
    INSERT INTO AbsenceInstances ( Racf, RecordDate )
    SELECT Absence.Racf, Absence.RecordDate
    FROM Absence
    WHERE ((Absence.RecordDate)>=#01/01/2017# And (Absence.RecordDate)<=#28/03/2017#);
```

Select Query:

```
Sql = "SELECT AbsenceInstances.Racf, Count(AbsenceInstances.RecordDate) AS CountOfRecordDate"
Sql = Sql & " FROM AbsenceInstances LEFT JOIN (select Racf, [RecordDate]+IIf(Weekday([RecordDate],7)=1,2,1) as RecordDate2 from AbsenceInstances) AS t2 ON (AbsenceInstances.RecordDate = t2.RecordDate2) AND (AbsenceInstances.Racf = t2.Racf)"
Sql = Sql & " WHERE (((t2.RecordDate2) Is Null))"
Sql = Sql & " GROUP BY AbsenceInstances.Racf;"
```

Can't thank Tom enough for his help. I hope this summation is useful for anyone else in the future.